# Python - Single Line Conditional syntax error?

Tags: python, logic, conditional-statements

I'm testing this to count the number of even numbers vs the number of odd numbers in the first 3 elements of an array.

This works:

```
 for i in range(3):
    if int(numbers[i]) % 2 == 0:
        ev +=1
    else:
        od +=1
    print(ev, od)
```

But this gives me an error:

```
for i in range(3):
        ev += 1 if numbers[i] % 2 == 0 else od += 1
        print(ev, od)

ev += 1 if numbers[i] % 2 == 0 else od += 1
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Inline `if`/`else` is for values. So, in the `else` case, it's reading as:

```
ev += od += 1
```

That doesn't make sense. In this case, inline `if`/`else`, aka the ternary conditional, is not appropriate.